# read simple Json in localhost on android

Tags: android, json

```
{
    "TopNews": [{
        "id": "5",
        "title": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/title5",
        "image": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/image5",
        "description": "desc5",
        "canComment": true
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/title4",
        "image": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/image4",
        "description": "desc4",
        "canComment": true
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/title3",
        "image": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/image3",
        "description": "desc3",
        "canComment": true
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/title2",
        "image": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/image2",
        "description": "description2",
        "canComment": true
    }, {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/title1",
        "image": "http:\/\/Test\/news_images\/image1",
        "description": "desc1",
        "canComment": true
    }]
}
```

what i want to read and show in my app is "id" tag.please someone tell me a simple way.Any help is highly appreciated.please guys.

Comment: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Comment: thanks Anirudh.but there's a problem.the json data is in my local machine.is this method suits localhost also???

Comment: Can you explain a bit?  You have an android app that's reading data from your localhost which is your machine or the device itself DO you have the json stored as a local file or are you making an http call to your machine (localhost) which is serving this data? In either case, parsing remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Start that by creating your own custom object **News** which has all the attribute id,title,image...

Then fill the object while parsing the JSON object as follow:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject json = getJSONfromURL("localhost/SericeReturnsJSONObject.whatEver");

try 
{
   ArrayList<News> alNewsListfromJson = alGetNewsList(json);
}
catch (JSONException e) 
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

```
private ArrayList<News> alGetNewsList(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {

  JSONArray TopNews = json.getJSONArray("TopNews");
  News oNews = null;
  ArrayList<News> alNewslist = new ArrayList<News>(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < TopNews.length(); i++) {

      JSONObject oJSONObject = shows.getJSONObject(i);
      oNews = new News();

      oNews.setNewsID(oJSONObject.getString("id"));     
      oNews.setNewsTitle(oJSONObject.getString("title")); 
      // .. etc

      alNewslist.add(oNews);
      oNews = null;
  }
 return alNewslist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject fullJObj = new JSONObject(myStr);
JSONArray jArr = fullJObj.getJSONArray("TopNews");
for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); ++i ) {
    JSONObject jObj = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = jObj.getString("id");
}
```

For more information, go to:

- [JSONObject documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).
- [JSONArray documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html).
- [JSON documentation](http://json.org)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readTwitterFeed);.....
```

see this simple example...
that may help you

Answer (score 0):

Use **JSONObject** and **JSONArray** classes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

The web is crawling with simple examples for Android.

Basically what you need to do is:

- Load the String into a JSONObject
- Make a JSONArray out of TopNews
- Goes through it and get id

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(payload); // payload is your JSON
JSONArray my_news = jsonObject.getJSONArray("TopNews");

List<int> my_ids = new ArrayList<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < my_news.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject my_object = my_news.getJSONObject(i);
   int id = Integer.parseInt(my_object.getString("id"));
   my_ids.push(id);
}
```

Don't forget to surround with try/catch when needed.